# Sorting a LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am having trouble with sorting my linked list can anyone help me and let me know what I am doing wrong?
I need to sort in and put it in a list.
and If you can give me some pointers to print the list at the end with a new method public void print().

```
    public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
             extends LinkedList<T> 
    {
        private LinkedList<T> list;  //the sorted list

        //the constructor
        public SortedLinkedList(LinkedList<T> in)
        {
            if(in.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Empty list");
            }
            else
            {
                 LinkedList<T> first = new LinkedList<T>(in.subList(0, in.size()/2));
                 LinkedList<T> second = new LinkedList<T>(in.subList(in.size   ()/2,in.size()));
                 LinkedList<T> sortList = new LinkedList<T>();

                 int i = 0;
                 int j = 0;
                 while(i<first.size() && j<second.size())
                 {
                     if(first.get(i).equals(second.get(j)) || first.get(i).compareTo(second.get(j))<0)
                     {
                          sortList.add(first.get(i));
                          i++;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          sortList.add(second.get(j));
                          j++;
                     }
                     if(i == first.size())
                     {
                          for(int k = j; k<second.size(); k++)
                          {
                              sortList.add(second.get(k));
                          }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          for(int x = i; x<first.size(); x++)
                          {
                              sortList.add(first.get(x));
                     }
                }

            }
         }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Please describe what's happening versus what you expect to happen; just saying "something's wrong" isn't helpful. Also, if this is homework, please tag it as such :)

Answer (score 2):

Before writing your own sort try [Collections.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29). If you need your own sort order, use a Comparator.

Some addition: In most cases, LinkedLists are the wrong data structure - especially if there's the need for sorting it.

Comment: +1 For the insightful comment on selecting the correct data structure

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to implement [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). If my assumption is correct, you are forgetting to call mergesort on the sublists.recursively. The rough algorithm, in pseudo code, would be:

```
mergesort(list)
    left = list[:len(list/2)]
    right = list[len(list/2):]

    mergesort(left)
    mergesort(right)

    merge(left, right) # that would be your while loop
```

Edit: Unless you really need to implement your own algorithm, I suggest using [Collections.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), from the Java API.